# Make PHP Imagick use more resources

Tags: php, performance, imagemagick, imagick

I have a basic function that iterates through an array of x,y coordinates to create a series of PNG images (below). I'm working on optimizing the performance of this script, but upgrading my server from 1 CPU/2GB RAM --> 16 CPUs (same clock speed)/32GB RAM didn't make a difference on the execution time.

I've monitored the memory usage through several processes, and it never seems to utilize more than ~700mb RAM. Is there any way I could modify this script to utilize more resources on my server?

```
function annotateFrames($text, $x, $y) {
    for ($i = 0; $i <= 100; $i++) {
        $image = new Imagick();
        $draw = new ImagickDraw();
        $pixel = new ImagickPixel('yellow');
        $image->newImage(1920, 1080, $pixel);
        $draw->setFillColor('blue');
        $image->annotateImage($draw, $x[$i], $y[$i], 0, $text);
        $image->setImageFormat('png');
        $image->setOption('png:bit-depth', '16');
        $image->setOption('png:color-type', 6);
        $image->writeImage('path/'.$i.'.png');
    }
}
```

Comment: Since your code processes in a serial manner there is no way you can use more resources. You'd have to switch to a parallel approach. But this whole things seems odd... why would you want to recreate `png`s all the time? Can't you cache them?

Comment: @arkascha, thank you. What would a basic 'parallel' approach look like? The array of coordinates creates different text positions, creating frames for a video.

Comment: You cannot implement parallel processing directly in php, that is not what php is made for. Take a look at job queuing systems instead. So you just create the jobs by means of php and then have a scheduler fire one process per job. Those processes can obviously work in parallel. Then php can collect the results as soon as the jobs get marked as done.

Comment: You could try setting resource limits... `Imagick::setResourceLimit(Imagick::RESOURCETYPE_MEMORY,8000000000)`

Comment: What problem are you trying to solve by "making Imagick use more resources" ?

Comment: @MarkSetchell, thank you I will try this!

Comment: @Danack, In my original post I wrote: "I'm working on optimizing the performance of this script". I would think that 'making Imagick use more [available] resources' could allow for faster script execution times.

Comment: @user1661677 you should always ask the actual question, rather than assume a possible answer aka http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem